# Angular constructor is not executing method

Tags: angular

I am trying to separate my code as much as possible and I have data service, where I initialise headers in constructor, but they are not being set.

Method is SetHeaders() in constructor. Headers are not set. Do I have to use OnInit instead in component?

```
import { Headers, Http, Response, Request, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from '../../auth/resourceownerpassword/services/auth.service';

import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private _endpointUrl: string;
    private _headers: Headers;
    private _options: RequestOptions;
    private _apiEndpoint: string;
    public data: any;

    constructor(public http: Http, public authService: AuthService) {
        this.SetHeaders();
    }

    public SetEndpoint(endpointUrl: string) {
        this._endpointUrl = environment.API_URL + endpointUrl;
    }

    public SetHeaders() {

        console.log('setHeaders started');

        this._headers = new Headers();
        this._headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this._headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        let token = this.authService.GetToken();

        console.log("Token auth serv: " + token);

        if (token !== '') {
            let tokenValue = 'Bearer ' + token;
            console.log('tokenValue:' + tokenValue);
            this._headers.append('Authorization', tokenValue);
        }

        this._options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this._headers });
    }

    public Get = (): Observable<any[]> => {
        return this.http.get(this._endpointUrl, this._options).map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json());
    }

    public GetSingle = (id: number): Observable<any> => {
        return this.http.get(this._endpointUrl + '/' + id, this._options).map(res => <any>res.json());
    }

    public Post = (item: any): Observable<any> => {
        return this.http.post(this._endpointUrl, JSON.stringify(item), this._options).map(res => <any>res.json());
    }

    public Put = (item: any): Observable<any> => {
        return this.http.put(this._endpointUrl, JSON.stringify(item), this._options).map(res => <any>res.json());
    }

    public Delete = (id: number): Observable<any> => {
        return this.http.put(this._endpointUrl + '/' + id, null, this._options).map(res => <any>res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: it's probably being constructed before you have the token in your auth service. Do this with an observable instead. Or it's possible that you can't share request options between requests. But there are 3 better options for doing this over what you're doing, 1. simplest, set the headers per request, 2. extend the http service instead and set the headers there.  3. use http interceptors instead

Comment: I don't like 1, it is constant repetition, it worked with 1, but I want it in one place. 2 is feasible, but I will go with 3 since I remember I wanted to do it, and especially with Angular4 there is HttpInterceptor class which makes implementation easier. Please put as answer I'll mark it

Comment: constant repetition is what computers are best at. but saying "do it differently" isn't really an answer to the question asked, I truthfully am not sure why you can't seem to share request options between requests, seems like you should, so no need for this to be an answer.